# Why does my R Shiny App disconnect in a browser?

Tags: r, shinyapps

this R Shiny app works just fine on its own, but when I deploy, it gives me out-of-memory errors in the logs. All it is doing is displaying a small (1-2MB) raster over the default map. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

```
# test the display of a GCS image.

library(shiny)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("MountainSnow Map"),
  helpText("Attempt to plot a raster"),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           leafletOutput(outputId = 'map'),
           fluidRow(
             column(12,
                    verbatimTextOutput("info")),
             fluidRow(
               column(12,
                      plotOutput("distPlot")),
                    )
                    )
        )
        )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  tmp.url <- "/vsicurl/https://storage.googleapis.com/cso_test_upload/co_n_domain/swed_wi_assim/2023_04_01_swed_wi_assim.tif"
  ras <- raster(tmp.url)
  
  #ras <- writePNG(ras)
  
  #cont. colormap option
  #pal <- colorNumeric(c("#0C2C84", "#41B6C4", "#FFFFCC"), values(ras),
  #                    na.color = "transparent")
  #discrete colormap option
  pal <- colorBin(c("#0C2C84", "#41B6C4", "#FFFFCC"), values(ras), 6, pretty = TRUE,
                      na.color = "transparent")
  
  output$map = renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addRasterImage(ras, colors = pal, opacity = 0.8) %>%
      setView(lng = -110, lat = 40, zoom = 4) %>%
      addLegend(pal = pal, values = values(ras), title = "SWE (m)")
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```